# Can somebody please explain why more specific inputs are bad?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

[Flow's documentation states](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-more-specific-inputs-bad):

Given a class:

> ```
> class BaseClass {
>   method(value: City): City { ... }
> }
> ```

And a subclass:

> ```
> class SubClass extends BaseClass {
>   method(value: SanFrancisco): City { ... } // ERROR!!
> }
> ```
>
> This is an error in Flow because if you are expecting a SanFrancisco and you get a City you could be using something that only exists on SanFrancisco which would cause an error at runtime.

If I'm invoking `SubClass#method`, wouldn't I be forced by type checker to provide `SanFrancisco`? Why flow makes it an error?

Comment: That's an error in OOP generally; the subclass has a different interface to the parent. See the Liskov substitution principle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that both `Seattle` and `SanFrancisco` directly extend `City`, i.e.

```
class City { location: [number, number]; }
class Seattle extends City { raining: bool; }
class SanFrancisco extends City { foggy: bool; }
```

Whereas `BaseClass.prototype.method` will accept instances of `City`, `Seattle`, and `SanFrancisco` and possibly use `location`, your `SubClass.prototype.method` is free to use `foggy` even though `Seattle` lacks the property. This means that `SubClass.prototype.method` cannot generally be substituted for `BaseClass.prototype.method`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Function_types.